# Confused about EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to make an example for uploading files using jquery . I have created a table with fields FileId,FileName,Filesize,FileExtention,filecontent  and then add a entity datamodel called my model then wrote this code just like in the youtube video.But Visual Studio says

> System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery' Does not contain a definition for 'Add' Are you missing an assembly reference

```
**dc.Uploaded.Add(new Uploaded**
```

But I have added `System.Data.Entity` and  also added `using ProjectsModel;`

```
  {
        using (ProjectsEntities dc = new ProjectsEntities())
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dc.Uploaded.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void btnUploadAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection filesColl = Request.Files;
        using (ProjectsEntities dc = new ProjectsEntities())
        {
            foreach (string uploader in filesColl)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = filesColl[uploader];

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);

                    byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                    dc.Uploaded.Add(new Uploaded
                    {
                        FileID = 0,
                        FileName = file.FileName,
                        ContentType = file.ContentType,
                        FileExtention = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName),
                        FileSize = file.ContentLength,
                        FileContent = buffer
                    });
                }
            }
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
        PopulateUploadedFiles(); // for refresh grid data
```

Comment: you meant compile error?

Comment: Can you show your data context class?

Comment: What does `ProjectsEntities` look like?

Comment: How did you create `ProjectsEntities` and what does IntelliSense give you?

Comment: How about showing us the link to the video. Otherwise, how do we know what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded is the entity class name, right? Try:

```
dc.Uploadeds.Add
```

It is obvious that you cannot use Add on the entity itself, entity classes do not define an Add method unless you explicitly write one of yours. OTOH entity collections have an Add method through inheritance. By convention VS generates collections using plurals of the entity class. So it should be:

```
dc.Uploadeds.Add( ... )
```

Is that clear now?